# Spring Boot (2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT) application can't start with Jetty

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jetty

I want to start a Spring Boot application but it is not possible due to:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-07-05 15:51:19.216 ERROR 10080 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.sc.pps.Application.main(Application.java:42) [main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.newSessionHandler(ServletContextHandler.java:296) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.getSessionHandler(ServletContextHandler.java:391) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.relinkHandlers(ServletContextHandler.java:199) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:171) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.<init>(WebAppContext.java:289) ~[jetty-webapp-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.<init>(WebAppContext.java:211) ~[jetty-webapp-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.<init>(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:28) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(JettyServletWebServerFactory.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionIdListener"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:898) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:668) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:761) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.<clinit>(SessionHandler.java:140) ~[jetty-server-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
    ... 18 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52640', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have never seen such error before and researching it does not lead to any working solution(s).

Do somebody know what's going on here?

*Update*

My Gradle Dependencies:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    maven { url "http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotool" }
    maven { url "http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository" }
    maven { url "http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/" }
    maven { url "http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/" }
    maven { url "http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    dependencies {
        dependencySet (group: 'org.hibernate', version: '5.2.8.Final') {
            entry 'hibernate-core'
            entry 'hibernate-entitymanager'
            entry 'hibernate-spatial'
        }

        dependency (group: 'io.prometheus', name: 'simpleclient_spring_boot', version: '0.0.21')

        dependencySet (group: 'io.github.resilience4j', version: '0.9.0-SNAPSHOT') {
            entry 'resilience4j-spring-boot'
            entry 'resilience4j-metrics'
            entry 'resilience4j-prometheus'
        }

        dependencySet (group: 'org.apache.ignite', version: '1.9.0') {
            entry 'ignite-core'
            entry 'ignite-spring'
            entry 'ignite-rest-http'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')

    compile('io.prometheus:simpleclient_spring_boot')

    compile('io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot') {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
    }

    compile('io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-metrics') {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
    }

    compile('io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-prometheus') {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
    }

    compile('org.apache.ignite:ignite-core')
    compile('org.apache.ignite:ignite-spring')
//    compile('org.apache.ignite:ignite-rest-http')

    compile('com.h2database:h2')

    compile(group: 'org.apache.hive', name: 'hive-jdbc', version: '2.1.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
    }

    compile(group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-hadoop', version: '2.4.0.RELEASE')
    compile(group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-hadoop-config', version: '2.4.0.RELEASE')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('junit:junit')
}
```

Comment: You are using a `2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`, so it might be the case. I was using WebFlux with Netty a while ago with a similar version and had some issues also. Can you try upgrading to `M2` — or even `M3` if it's out already?

Comment: maybe you ["included multiple servlet apis"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2058#issuecomment-66359100) ?

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionIdListener"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

That means you have the `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionIdListener` in your classpath more then once (and one or more of them are in a signed jar file).

Cleanup your dependencies, ensure you only have a single servlet-api jar.

Since you are using Jetty 9.4.6, the [servlet-api 3.1 jar](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.servlet%7Cjavax.servlet-api%7C3.1.0%7Cjar) coordinates on `central.maven.org` are ...

```
compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
```

**How to list all jars with class**

Create a class to dump the locations of the class you are interested in.  This is created as a junit testcase so it can be run within the same gradle dependencies as your project.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionIdListener;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ClasspathTest
{
    @Test
    public void testJavaServlet() throws IOException
    {
        ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        String classAsResource = HttpSessionIdListener.class.getName().replace('.','/') + ".class";
        Enumeration<URL> urls = cl.getResources(classAsResource);
        System.out.printf("Looking for: %s%n",classAsResource);
        while (urls.hasMoreElements())
        {
            URL url = urls.nextElement();
            System.out.printf("Found: %s%n",url.toExternalForm());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I find the duplicate?

Comment: @Mulgard see answer above